# Utilizing instances of a class meeting multiple conditions without lists

Tags: python, list, class

I want to know to how to find instances of a class which meet some conditions and use them without applying python lists.

```
class d1():
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
f0=d1(2,1)
f1=d1(2,3)
f2=d1(2,4)
f3=d1(4,4)
```

In this case I want to find instances which have `a==2` and `b<4` (`f0` and `f1`) and use them without applying python lists. I want to know how they are dealt with in other languages which don't have buckets like python lists.

So there are 2 questions:

1. multi-condition instance finding
2. dealing with objects without using python lists.

Python lists are dynamic that you can put anything in them, but other languages like C doesn't have something like this, so how would the answer be if this question was dealt to those other languages, what is its equivalent in python?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what do you mean by _"use them if they are no python lists"_? The variables `f0` and `f1` are already not lists right?

Comment: python lists are dynamic list that you can put anything in them but other languages like c don't have something like this so how the answer of this question is dealt with there and what is it equivalent in python.

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano they are instances of class d1, right?

Comment: Yes, they are of type `d1`. With regards to other languages, I believe C++ has `std::vector` which is somehow like a dynamic list/array.

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano so what about the finding multicondition instances and putting them in list?

Comment: If the number of instances you would create isn't fixed, so it may grow from 4 to 1000 or even more infinitely, then we need to design a data structure that can resize by itself, either reallocate itself to another bigger memory chunk, or spawn another chunk to put just the additional items. But why would we do that if we already have builtins such as `list`. So in summary, if you don't like `list`, we have to reimplement our own `list`-like data structure :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/739936/revisions
this somehow helpful but I needed more easier ways like where method which is implemented in sql.

Comment: Most low level languages allow you to have a collection of references, e.g. in C if you want to keep track of structs fulfilling some set of conditions, you could have an array (or linked list) of pointers to those those structs which fulfill the required conditions. In higher level languages you usually get containers which work similarity to Python lists, e.g. Java vectors allow you to store an arbitrary number of objects.

Comment: @FarhangAmaji I updated my answer to support any condition. Perhaps it better suits what you need than my previous answer which used a fixed condition.

Answer (score 1):

For sake of simplicity I added a `__str__` method for a more readable print.
You need to use the built-in function `globals` to access to a dictionary of the global scope of the program. I don't think it is a good practice to start with but... here the code.

```
class d1():
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.a} {self.b}'

f0=d1(2,1)
f1=d1(2,3)
f2=d1(2,4)
f3=d1(4,4)
   
d1_list = [f for k, f in globals().items() if isinstance(f, d1)]

print([print(f) for f in d1_list if f.a == 2 and f.b < 4]) # you can omit the internal print
```

Output

```
2 1
2 3
[None, None] # it is a consequence of the __str__
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new instance of `d1`
2. You can choose to either:

   a. Get the reference to the object itself

   b. Get a [weak reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#module-weakref) to the object. The benefit of this is that the reference would not keep the object alive if it can already be deleted.
3. To not use a `list` or any fixed-size containers, use a linked-list `d1._instances` (a class attribute), where we would append each new instance to the tail of the linked-list.
4. To simplify the iteration of `d1._instances`, make it [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types).
5. Filter the instances that satisfies the given condition.

```
import weakref


class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

    def __iter__(self):
        current = self
        while current:
            yield current.value()  # Operation () is to access the value of the weak reference
            current = current.next


class d1:
    _instances = None
    _instances_tail = None

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

        self._store_instance()

    def _store_instance(self):
        current = Node(weakref.ref(self))  # Or just <Node(self)> if you choose 2.a above
        if not self._instances:
            d1._instances = current
        else:
            d1._instances_tail.next = current
        d1._instances_tail = current

    @staticmethod
    def get_instances(condition=lambda value: True):  # Default behavior is get everything
        return filter(condition, d1._instances)


f0=d1(2,1)
f1=d1(2,3)
f2=d1(2,4)
f3=d1(4,4)

print("\nall")
for instance in d1.get_instances():
    print(type(instance), instance.a, instance.b)

print("\na == 2 and b < 4")
for instance in d1.get_instances(condition=lambda value: value.a == 2 and value.b < 4):
    print(type(instance), instance.a, instance.b)

print("\na == 2 and b >= 3")
for instance in d1.get_instances(condition=lambda value: value.a == 2 and value.b >= 3):
    print(type(instance), instance.a, instance.b)

print("\na == 4")
for instance in d1.get_instances(condition=lambda value: value.a == 4):
    print(type(instance), instance.a, instance.b)
```

**Output**

```
all
<class '__main__.d1'> 2 1
<class '__main__.d1'> 2 3
<class '__main__.d1'> 2 4
<class '__main__.d1'> 4 4

a == 2 and b < 4
<class '__main__.d1'> 2 1
<class '__main__.d1'> 2 3

a == 2 and b >= 3
<class '__main__.d1'> 2 3
<class '__main__.d1'> 2 4

a == 4
<class '__main__.d1'> 4 4
```